# How to return boolean value in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a following table

```
id  person  type counted  expected
1      a     A     0        1
2      a     A     1        0
3      a     B     1        0
4      a     B     2        0
5      a     B     3        4
6      b     C     0        0
```

First I'd like to group by `type` and aggregate by summing `counted` and `expected`

```
person type sum(counted)  sum(expected)
a      A      1            1
a      B      6            4
b      C      0            0
```

Then I'd like to add boolean whether `sum(counted)`equal`sum(expected)` or not.

```
person type sum(counted)  sum(expected)  counted=expected
a      A      1            1              true
a      B      6            4              false
b      C      0            0              true
```

And then I'd like to group by in `person` and return boolean with `and` in `person`

```
person  has_false
a        false
b        true
```

Are there any way to achieve this?

I went halfway but didn't proceed yet.

```
select person,type,sum(counted),sum(expected)
from table
group by person,type
```

If someone has opinion,please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.  I've laid it out like you described but I don't think you need to sum by person, type - rather just summing by person will work (for this example).

```
drop table if exists test;
create table test (id  int, person  varchar(1), typ varchar(1), counted  int, expected int);

insert into test values
(1, 'a', 'A', 0, 1),
(2, 'a', 'A', 1, 0),
(3, 'a', 'B', 1, 0),
(4, 'a', 'B', 2, 0),
(5, 'a', 'B', 3, 4),
(6, 'b', 'C', 0, 0);

with grouped as (
select person, typ, sum(counted) as scount, sum(expected) as ecount, scount = ecount as equal
from test
group by person,typ
)
select person, bool_and(equal) as has_false
from grouped
group by person;
```